# Simple ES7 decorator with babel

Tags: javascript, gulp, decorator, babeljs, ecmascript-2016

I can not run this code:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-decorators#readonly

I use gulp and babel. I have package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-first-decorator",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "core-decorators": "^0.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.0.14",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators": "^6.0.14",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.2",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "browserify": "^12.0.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

and I have gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    return browserify({entries: 'app.js', extensions: ['.js'], debug: true})
        .transform('babelify', {
            presets: ['es2015'],
            plugins: ['transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators']
        })
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

my app.js

```
import { readonly } from 'core-decorators';

class Meal {
  @readonly
  entree = 'steak';
}

var dinner = new Meal();
dinner.entree = 'salmon';
// Cannot assign to read only property 'entree' of [object Object]
```

I write to the console:

```
$ npm install
$ gulp
```

I open my browser, but the console is an empty.
There should be: Cannot assign to read only property 'entree' of [object Object]

My app after compile:

```
var _coreDecorators = require('core-decorators');

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

var Meal = function Meal() {
  _classCallCheck(this, Meal);
};

var dinner = new Meal();
dinner.entree = 'salmon';
// Cannot assign to read only property 'entree' of [object Object]
```

Comment: Can you show us the transpilation result?

Comment: Yes, I added results.

Comment: @Bergi for the next several months 90% of questions about babel will be about not plugging the correct preset/plugin :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `stage-1` preset, since decorators are non-standardised yet (so they are not and will not be included into the `es2015` preset).

https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-1/

Comment: I added stage-1:
$ npm install babel-preset-stage-1 --save-dev
I added in gulpfile:
{
presets: ['es2015', 'stage-1'],
plugins: ['transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators']
}
but the result is the same. Can you give a more detailed response?

Comment: @user2815962 what if you swap them? stage-1 first followed by es2015

Comment: @user2815962 hm, I spent some time and I can confirm that it does not work :-S

Comment: Decorators currently **do not work** with Babel 6. The issue is being tracked here:  
https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T2645

Answer (score 0):

I installed packages:

```
$ npm install core-decorators
$ npm install gulp browserify vinyl-source-stream
$ npm install babelify@6.4.0
```

!!!!! babelify - 6.4.0
seventh version was not able to run

gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var babelify = require('babelify');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    return browserify({entries: 'app.js', extensions: ['.js'], debug: true})
        .transform(babelify, {
            stage: 0
        })
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app'));
});
```

and last command :)

```
$ gulp
```