# decoratorsBeforeExport Error when using electron-webpack dev

Tags: javascript, webpack, electron, babeljs

I was trying to convert my react project into an electron-app. As 
the project is bundled via webpack, I began using electron-webpack for 
the build. When running `electron-webpack dev`, neither the **/main** nor the **/renderer** compiles correctly.

Console logs throw Decorator plugin error

```
The decorators plugin requires a 'decoratorsBeforeExport' option,
 whose value must be a boolean. If you want to use the 
legacy decorators semantics, you can set the 'legacy: true' option
```

Sooo, why not following that wise suggestion?. Then, I updated all my dependencies and update my `.babelrc` file, for adding the **decoratorsBeforeExport** and the **legacy** option (*false* and *true* respectively)

```
"plugins": [
   ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", {
     "decoratorsBeforeExport": false,
     "legacy": true,
   }],
```

As the Error still showing after that, I open the `plugin-proposal-decorators`folder from _/node_modules_ and added a log for the *options*. Apparently, it does not identify my options set. I tried
directly from the webpack loader config, but the problem still showing.

**My env**

- Node: v11.2.0
- Webpack: v4.29.0
- @babel/core: v7.0.0

Answer (score 0):

This `.babelrc` worked for me:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-react",
    [ "@babel/preset-env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": [ "last 1 version" ]
      }
    } ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose" : true }]
  ]
}
```

Mind how `decorators` plugin comes before `class-properties`.

Somehow, it didn't work for me in non-`legacy` mode. `loose` option is required if `decorators` runs in `legacy` mode, according to official docs: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-proposal-decorators.html

It also states:

> In Babel 7, [transform-decorators-legacy](https://github.com/loganfsmyth/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy) will be the default plugin in Stage-0.
>   (Source: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-decorators.html)

More info:
[Babel 7 - Decorators transform doesn't work with babel-loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51857423/babel-7-decorators-transform-doesnt-work-with-babel-loader)
[Simple ES7 decorator with babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635511/simple-es7-decorator-with-babel)